# Does RedirectToAction pose a security risk?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an HTTPS post coming in via a secure form.  Without going into lengthy explanation:  I need to call an action within the same controller that accepts two tokens passed as parameters.  When I run Fiddler, I see that that method is being called with the parameters in the URL.  My question is:  Does this pose a security risk?  Is there a more secure way of redirecting within the same controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it poses a security risk, but it is easily mitigated by simply validating that the urls you are redirecting to are within the same domain as your source destination.

In fact, this is on the OWASP top 10.

[A10 - Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A10-Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards)

EDIT:

I just realized that I missed the "ToAction" part of the question, so no.. It's not really possible to redirect outside of the site with RedirectToAction, so there isn't a worry for that.  However, if you are using direct user input to feed into your RedirectToAction (and that includes accepting post data that you generate in a different page) then it's possible that an attacker could redirect to a method you did not anticipate.  However, this is no different from a user simply trying random URL's and hitting one, or knowing a url and going to it manually.  You need to have authorization in place to prevent access to URL's that the user does not have authorization to view.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm definitely doing the redirect within the same domain.  I'm doing it within the same controller.  So I'm assuming that's safe then?  From what I read in the article it is.  I'm more concerned about a hacker intercepting the parameters being past from one action results to another..  Is this something I need to worry about?

Comment: @kickinchicken - you're not quite understanding.  If you accept an input that is used in a redirect, you must validate that this input is in fact a url that is to your domain.  Just because you're only sending url's from your domain doesn't mean you're safe.  You have to validate the inputs.

Comment: I  see what you're sayimg Erik.  No the input isn't being used in the redirect.  The redirect is static.   Also - and I should have explained this earlier but it's part of an SSO process.  We accept a form post, do some work and then redirect to action.  The inputs are two strimgs, neither of which are being redirected to.  Do I have to worry that when the redirect to the GET get happens that an outside hacker can intercept this?

Comment: @kickinchicken - Ok, so if you are not using posted data as your redirect destination and are instead redirecting to a known whitelist then you are fairly safe.  At that point, you need to just follow standard authentication and/or validation rules for input to ensure safety.  You don't have to worry about interception if your destinations also require authentication, since they can intercept all they want.. but if they don't have the authentication they won't get into the target urls.

Comment: Thanks @Erik Funkenbusch

Answer (score 2):

If the original Action is accessed via HTTPS then `RedirectToAction` will redirect to a relative URL on the same domain using the same protocol.

So if your original page is

```
https://www.example.com/Foo/Bar
```

and this redirects to the `FooBar` action with some route parameters:

```
https://www.example.com/Foo/FooBar/1/2/3
```

an attacker *cannot* read the parameters `1/2/3` nor the rest of the URL.

However, the things you should bear in mind are:

- The URL parameters will be logged by default by the browser (history), your server, by corporate proxy servers and possibly by other devices on your network by default.
- If the user follows any links from your page to other `https` URLs, the `referer` HTTP header will contain your page address including parameters. Modern browsers will not send the `referer` header with `http` links though.
- If there are any other `https` resources on your page this will cause the browser to send the `referer` header with the request.

For these reasons, if your parameters (`1/2/3`) are private, then you may wish to `POST` this data to the target page rather than use `RedirectToAction` (which results in a `GET`).

Note that you should be validating that the current user has access to the resources that `1/2/3` refers to (e.g. if the parameters were an order ID, you should check that the user identified by their auth cookies allow them to see the order referenced). Keeping `1/2/3` private are only beneficial if the parameters are themselves sensitive (e.g. a social security number).

Note that the OWASP Top 10 vulnerability, "A10 - Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards" does not apply here as `RedirectToAction` can only redirect to another action. If the other action redirects to a user set URL, then the vulnerability would lie there instead.

Comment: This seems like the better answer, as it sheds light on parameters and possibilities of sensitive data being logged somewhere you don't want it to. Thanks for the tips!